# Displaying custom background images based on screen resolution

Tags: javascript, css, security, background-image, screen-resolution

For a site, I need to be able to dynamically display background images depending on the user's screen resolution.

I.e when the page starts loading, within the `<head>` a small javascript loads, which sets the page's background via css to something like `http://example.com/backgrounds/beach_800x600` where 800 and 600 is the screen resolution determined via the javascript.

I'm creating various resized images for the most common screen resolutions, so that for most people there will be an exact match of their screen resolution with an existing image. If there's not an exact match made, e.g if a user has a screen resolution `AxB` for which there's no existing image, then an image will be created & resized to `AxB` on the fly, and will be served. From then on, anyone with the resolution `AxB` would be served that image.

The questions I have are:

1) Is this a safe method? I.e I don't want more than 50 custom sized images created for custom screen resolutions. Would I be able to stay in that ball park with this method? And are there any other security risks I should be aware of with this method?

2) Should I give it an error margin of say 50 or 100 pixels, so if someone's resolution is 700x900, and I don't have that but I have 600x800 or I have 800x1000, then I would serve those existing images rather than create new ones? If so, should I set the margin at 100 pixels or is there a better number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the use of CSS3 Media Queries and the `background-size` property, there's virtually no need for JS other than for compatibility purposes with out-dated browsers.

[**Here's a link**](http://www.dochub.io/#css/background-size) with details about `background-size`. This property allows you to scale the image in various ways, regardless of the users resolution. Sometimes this might not be ideal.

[**And so we have CSS3 Media Queries**](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/). With these, you can target certain resolutions (or greater than and less than certain resolutions) and tell the browser which image you would like to show accordingly (or even how to display it, with or without `background-size` as well).

Comment: Scaling the image thru background-size will cause it to look distorted, yes? With the media queries, the issue remains that I need to resize for the most common resolutions but if the user's resolution isn't in them, then i'd want to create a resized image for that on the fly

Comment: `background-size` can cause the image to become distorted, sure. However, let's pretend you create 3 background images; one for 800x600, one for 1024x768, and one for anything bigger than 1024x768. If you were to set `background-size:cover` to each respective background-image depending on the media query, the issue can be averted. Your media queries should resemble: `max-width: 800px`, `max-width: 1024px`, and `min-width: 1025px`, respectively.

Comment: @ClickUpvote This doesn't guarantee that the visitor will see the entire background, as some styling will still occur, but I believe it to be a happy compromise, and a feasible one at that.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably not want to create an image for each screen resolution, and you would probably want to base it off the browser window size - not screen resolution.  Given that a window could be virtually *any* size, you might want to re-think this.

Also this can be done easily using CSS3 media selectors, not JavaScript (though it could also be done using JavaScript).

See here for some info about media queries http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

Comment: I don't want to have to load up a different image each time the browser is resized, I might go with window at the start of page load and then choose another.